# Searching List <dvd> C # not using LINQ

Tags: c#, list, search, methods, enums

I have a DVD Rental application. And in my `Store` (class) I need to search the `Dvd` (class) for un-rented DVDs and save the film from the `Movie` class in results in a list (`getAvailableDVD()`). 
`Movie` has properties set & a `List<Dvd>` & in my `Dvd` I have an enum for availability: `{Available,Rented,Not Available}`

I'm quite new to this idea, but I'm wanting to search the list for each `Availability.Available` and return its corresponding film(`Movie`)

anyone have ideas on how to approach a search method in my `Store` class?

```
class Movie
{
    string brand;
    public string BRAND
    {
        get{ return brand;}
    }
    List<Dvd> films = new List<Dvd>();
    public Movie(String brand)
    {
       this.brand = brand;  
    }
}

class DVD
{
     public int BARCODE{get;set}
     public Availability STATUS{ get;set;}
     public DateTime RENTALDATE { get; set; }
     public DateTime RENTALDUE { get; set; }
     public DVD(int barcode, Availability avail, DateTime out, DateTime in){
          this.BARCODE = barcode; this.STATUS = avail; this.RENTALDATE = out; this.RENTALDUE = in;
     }
}

class Store
{
    List<Movie> films = new List<Movie>();
    public void addFilmtoStore(-----all params from dvd & movie classes----);
}
```

Comment: It is hard to understand your question. Some code will help us understand.

Comment: Will you submit some code please and tell us where it fails or returns unexpteced results?

Comment: Use Linq or simply make a for loop?

Comment: this not a LINQ query ...this is a foreach list query

Comment: could fit the rest of the addfilm class (above) but that method creates instances of dvd & movie and adds them to the films list. Below is where i want to create a searching list method

Answer (score 3):

A readable approach would be using LINQ to query your lists:

```
public List<Movie> GetAvailableDVDs()
{
    List<Movie> availableFilms = GetAllDVDs() // presuming you have such a method
        .Where(dvd => dvd.STATUS == Availability.Available)
        .Select(dvd => dvd.Film)   
        .ToList();
    return availableFilms;
}
```

if you can't use LINQ it's similar:

```
public List<Movie> GetAvailableDVDs()
{
    List<Movie> availableFilms = new List<Movie>();
    foreach(DVD dvd in GetAllDVDs())
    {
        if(dvd.STATUS == Availability.Available)
        {
            availableFilms.Add(dvd.Film);
        }
    }
    return availableFilms;
}
```

Comment: im not using LINQ as part of my course, just foreach and lists ..simple

Comment: @KingBee: then use a simple loop and initialize the list manually, see my code

Comment: the film, is not part of the dvd class its from the movie class. this is part of my issue. would you know how to do that?

Comment: @KingBee: sorry, i must admit that i'm not no longer sure what you need and where you find it. Does my example help to solve the issue or not?

Comment: i pretty much had the same code also. except my for each was looking List<dvd> films list & you mention that method. i have now changed which works brilliant just need to save the corresponding film (details) to my list. 90% done